# Insufficient permissions to save file in /opt/lampp/htdocs/ in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I recently installed xampp server on Ubuntu 20.04

I've changed permissions for the folder /opt/lampp/htdocs/ as follows:

[image]

But whenever I try to save a file inside this folder in any code editor, it says insufficient permissions

[image]

File gets saved after Retry as Sudo, but I need to enter password each time when I edit and save a file.

Is there a way to fix this, so that sudo permission is no more required to create and save files in this folder ?

Comment: Did you check for the file permissions? You've only set the folder permissions to 777 (which is a horrible idea!). Also, this question is not related to PHP or programming

Comment: It's also not related to lamp or xampp. This is only about Ubuntu and it's file permissions.